# Ordered list with capital letters in PowerPoint?

Tags: ms-office

I'd like to create an ordered list in Powerpoint with capital letters as enumeration:

> Diagnostic Criteria
>
> A. Excessive anxiety and worry
>
> B. The individual finds it difficult to control the worry

I use PowerPoint for Mac 2011 (German version), the options that PP provides look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was originally posted as an edit by @what to @nadynes answer.  I include it for completeness sake.

---

### @what writes:

nadyne's answer gave me an idea how to solve this problem, so I'm attaching my solution to her answer. What I did was temporarily install the English version of Microsoft Office.

1. Move the Microsoft Office folder from the Applications folder of OS
   X to the trash and from there to some other place (like the
   Desktop). (You cannot directly move the Office folder elsewhere.
   Dragging it will only create an alias.)
2. Go to
   http://www.microsoft.com/germany/mac/office-2011-digital-download
   and download the English version of Microsoft Office. You need your
   product key for this.
3. Install MS Office.
4. Open the new English version of PowerPoint and create a new document
   with the ordered list, or open your existing document and create a
   new or re-format an existing list. Save the document.
5. Close PowerPoint, move the (English) MS Office folder from the
   Applications folder to the trash and from there to a save place to
   store it.
6. Drag and drop the old (German) MS Office folder back to the
   Applications folder.
7. Open your PP file in the German version of PowerPoint. Voila, you
   have a list with capital letter numberging :-) You can even copy
   this list to other places in your document and edit the text. It
   will retain the capital letters.

Here is an image of the result. Note how the Numbering format menu does not offer the option for capital letters followed by a dot ("A."), but the list in the open document is nevertheless numbered in that way:

[image]

Notes: Office apps don't open when they're outside the Applications folder under OS 10.9, so you cannot have two parallel working installations but have to drag the MS Office folders around. You have to do a complete Office installation. Installing only the English version of PowerPoint into the German version of the MS Office folder will cause PP to crash upon startup. Also, the Office installer does not allow to choose a different place for installation, you have to install to the Applications folder. So move the German version before you install the English one.

The whole procedure including writing this edit took me 59 minutes (that's the time from my last comment to this edit). Next time will be much quicker, because I don't have to search, download and install MS Office or write an edit on Stackexchange :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the English version of PowerPoint 2011.

1. In PowerPoint, go to the Format menu.
2. Select "Bullets and Numbering".
3. Select "Numbering" in the right navigation panel.
4. Choose the appropriate method.

[image: Bullets and Numbering dialog]

Since there appears to be a difference between the English version and the German version, an imperfect workaround is to use a custom bullet.
[image: Bullets and Numbering dialog again]

This is imperfect for two reasons:

1. You would have to specify the bullet for every item on the slide that you want to be enumerated as such.
2. You can only specify a single character, so you only get "A" instead of "A." for your bullet.

Using this method, this is what your slide would look like:
[image: the resulting slide with imperfect enumeration]

You could expand on this idea further, which gets increasingly hacky.  For example, you could create a graphic that consists of "A. ", "B. ", "C. ", ... and then use those as your custom bullets.  Using graphics like this for custom bullets can cause difficulty if you want to update your slides in the future but don't have the original graphic file available.

Comment: PowerPoint does not provide an option to number a list with uppercase letters. I wouldn't have asked a question here, if it did.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see your graphic.  PowerPoint *does* provide the option to number a list with uppercase letters in the English version, which I presumed would be consistent in other languages.

Comment: No, I have to apologize. I uploaded the graphic after your answer. And, like you, I just didn't think that the options would differ between languages.